# Mathematica can't differentiate when variable name has subscript component

Tags: syntax, subscript

I am not pasting my input code here since the website modifies my code. Instead I am attaching a screenshot of my notebook.

**Issue**: I enter two separate commands (asking Mathematica to differentiate in both case). I expected the answers to be '2' and '0' respectively, but it spits out some weird thing in the second case. Please tell me what went wrong?

In short, I expect Mathematica to identify 'x' and 'x_{p}' (where '_' stands for subscript) as two independent variables while performing the differentiation but it looks like it has some trouble in identifying variable name with a subscript component.

[image]

Comment: This is perhaps the commonest problem associated with subscripts. See this site for multiple explanations

Comment: @mikado, you did not give the website. Please do so. And thanks!

Comment: This site means *this site*, Mma.SE :) -- Search this site for subscript, Symbolize and [the Notation package](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/guide/NotationPackage.html), for instance.

Comment: Please note that $x_p$ in your second example is *not* a symbol.  Rather, it is an expression that is a function of *two* separate symbols `Subscript[x,p]`, which merely *formats* as $x_p$.  Therefore, *Mathematica* uses the chain rule to differentiate, giving the *correct* result.  *Never* **ever** **EVER** use subscript to denote symbols.  Use `xp` instead.

Comment: If you *insist* on *Mathematica* interpreting $x_p$ as a totally independent symbol, then use the following two lines: `MakeBoxes[xp, StandardForm] := SubscriptBox["x", "p"];
MakeExpression[SubscriptBox["x", "p"], StandardForm] := 
 MakeExpression["xp", StandardForm]`.  Then in all subsequent evaluations in the session, `xp` will display as $x_p$, but will be interpreted as `xp` behind-the-scenes.  Only *then*, would `D[`$x_p$`,x]` yield zero as expected.  (Try also running `FullForm[`$x_p$`]` to understand what's going on).

Answer (score 4):

A subscripted symbol is an expression involving the symbol. It is not a new symbol. Here is what you are asking Mma to do:

```
D[Times[2, Subscript[x, p]], x]
```

This is an expression in `x`, so Mma does exactly what you ask it to: it differentiates an expression in `x` with respect to `x`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `` Notation` `` package to get $x_p$ treated as a symbol.

```
Needs["Notation`"]
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["x", "p"]]]
D[2*x⎵Subscript⎵p^2, x⎵Subscript⎵p]
4*x⎵Subscript⎵p
```

This looks rather strange in input form, but in standard form it looks as you would expect it to.

[image]

Or even more generally,

[image: cells]

Which is the same as

[image: grad]